# wc only files and not directories

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

the goal is to use `wc` but without showing the error message. The problem its `wc` the directory as well and my teacher want us to discover one way to disappear with it, but I cant get the correct code. Its for education proposal. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTZYk.png)

```
wc -l -w -m /etc/*conf
```

```
      88     467    3028 /etc/adduser.conf
     160     223    6566 /etc/ca-certificates.conf
wc: /etc/dconf: Is a directory
```

Comment: What language are you using, Bash? Please [edit] to clarify, and please add the relevant tag as well, like [tag:bash]. If it is Bash, then this is a duplicate: [Globbing for only files in Bash](/q/20745656/4518341). BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and check out [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Redirect stderr (2) from `wc` to /dev/null:

```
wc -l -w -m /etc/*conf 2>/dev/null
```